# Why zero fragment in backstack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

My simple **layout** only has a fragment placeholder:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

I firstly add a **1st fragment** to this placeholder:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, firstFragment, "first"); //I did not put to backstack
```

I have a **2nd fragment**, which replace the above fragment and **put it to back stack**:

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

//initialize an fragment instance
Fragment secondFragment = initSecondFragment(); 

//replace with the fragment 
fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, secondFragment, "second");

//Add transaction to back stack
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);

//commit the transaction
fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragTrans.commit();  

//The following log returns me 0 when counting the number of fragments in back stack, why?  
Log.v("nr of fragment in back stack", fragMgr.getBackStackEntryCount()+"");
```

But I end up with **0** fragment in back stack, why???

Comment: @Selvin, YES, I have committed the transaction, see my updated code in my post.

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Try this:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964409/why-fragmentmanagers-getbackstackentrycount-return-zero

Answer (score 4):

Try executePendingTransactions() before the Log to ensure that the commit it happens.
Like this:

```
fragMgr.executePendingTransactions();
Log.v("nr of fragment in back stack", fragMgr.getBackStackEntryCount()+"");
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in answer ... May be need wait that fragment was added ?
Try to get count by this

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("nr of fragment in back stack", fragMgr.getBackStackEntryCount()+"");  
            }
        },50);
```

Comment: You should not be using timers to listen to this type of changes... What if the transaction took longer than 50ms?

Comment: @tf.alves i know it is dirty solution, but it works for me. May be you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @dooplaye, unfortunately no, but, as a rule of thumb, you should never rely on a timer with a random interval.
About the problem at hand, I think the wrong fragment manager may be at cause, maybe he should be dealing with the child fragment manager

Answer (score 0):

try this for the first fragment

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, firstFragment, "first");
```

and this for the second fragment

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, secondFragment, "second");
```