# Why FragmentManager's getBackStackEntryCount() return zero?

Tags: android, fragment

```
private static void changeFragment(Fragment f, boolean init) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.info_content, f,f.getClass().getName());
        if(!init){
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
```

when I want to get the stack cout by call fm.getBackStackEntryCount(), it returns zero?

Comment: what is value of bool init?

Comment: whatever true or false,it always be zero.

Answer (score 29):

You have to call a `fm.executePendingTransactions()` after `ft.commit()` or before `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()`. Because the commit() only schedules the transactions for a later pass.

Comment: I know this answer is from 2 years ago but I am having similar issues and calling `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` after commit did not resolve the issue. Can you suggest any other changes?

Comment: When executePendingTransactions() is called after the commit(), an exception is thrown. If called before the getBackStackEntryCount(), then count is still zero.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem, in my case getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() was always returning zero.

My problem was I've using support fragments:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
// note getSupportFragmentManager() instead getFragmentManager()
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();

fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

and I've checking *getFragmentManager()* backStackEntryCount, which always returns zero (it's using another fragment manager):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();            
    }
}
```

instead of *getSupportFragmentManager*, which returns the correct number:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();         
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Omg, this is such a potential bugs source for all developers. Thanks man.

Answer (score 6):

It might be too late to answer this question. Hope this answer will help someone  anyway.

Mostly it depends on where you are actually calling getBackStackEntryCount() method. In my case, I was calling this method after calling super.onBackPressed(). The moment this method was got called, there was no fragment in back stack. That's why I was always receiving 0.

Right way of calling the method in onBackPressed() :

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        Log.d("class", "items in backstack " + backStackEntryCount);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is using [FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html)

```
fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Log.d("test", "backStackEntryCount: " + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late to answer this question. Hope this answer will help someone anyway.

You should getBackStackEntryCount() method in onResume().

It will be this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
    for (int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId());
    }
}
```

Good luck!