# getBackStackEntryCount() always returns 0 even after adding addToBackStack and executePendingTransactions()

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

I have two activities A and B. Activity A has a mapFragment and I am adding it to backstack. When I come back from to Actvity A from B, I want the fragment to show up in same state as I left it. But getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() is returning me 0. Here is my code:

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

When coming back from activity B, I have this to know number of getBackStackEntryCount():

```
System.out.println("Number of entries in backstack "+ getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
```

which is showing me 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 67):

I had a similar problem, in my case `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` was always returning zero.

My problem was I've using support fragments:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
// note getSupportFragmentManager() instead getFragmentManager()
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();

fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

and I've checking `getFragmentManager()` `backStackEntryCount`, which always returns zero (it's using another fragment manager):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();            
    }
}
```

instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`, which returns the correct number:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();         
    }
}
```

Comment: s, it really worked when I changed getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager().
Thanks for the answer..

Comment: but why? i'm using common Fragments with common Fragment Manager, how can i know what FM - common or support use in case?

Comment: it depends if you import 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager or 
android.app.FragmentManager

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

I have changed this line:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mMapFragment);
```

to this:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, mMapFragment);
```

Pretty sure if you replace a fragment then its not in the backstack :)

Comment: Besides switching `replace()` against `add()` you also need to add `.addToBackStack(null)`

Answer (score 2):

I has similar problem. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499948/3005202) i create below code in my activity, instead of fragment, and this solution work fine:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Log.d("ovech", "back stack changed");
            Log.d("ovech", "back stack count = " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
            } else {
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
                Log.d("ovech", "hello without icon");
            }
            toolbar.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you're adding and removing fragments.

If you are adding using **supportFragmentManager** you must use **supportFragmentManager** with backStackEntryCount.

If you use **fragmentManager** to add then you should use **fragmentManager** to get the amount of fragments (backStackEntryCount)

```
// **Kotlin**
// AddFragment
val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
ft.replace(R.id.activity_base_content, f)
ft.addToBackStack(null)
ft.commit()

// Get amount of fragments 
supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution (walk around) to detect Fragments, because in my example *FM.getBackStackEntryCount()* also returned 0 and *FM.executPendingTransactions* didn't work.

So here is how I add a new fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(contextLayout.getId(), toolFragment, FRAG_TOOL_TAG)
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.tool_frag_in, R.anim.tool_frag_out)
                        .commit();
```

And here is how i remove it:

```
Fragment prevTool = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TOOL_TAG);
        if(prevTool != null){
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(prevTool).commit();
        }else {
            intentCANCELED();
        }
```

Orginally founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584/remove-old-fragment-from-fragment-manager).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` . Simple solution. It's working for me.
You need to do it on your Activity

Answer (score 0):

google has deprecated `getFragmentManager()`, so always use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

[Check Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack()) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were using `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()` ,  try using `parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()` (Used in cases where we extend Fragments, like BaseFragment and add/replace inside that.)